# The alien was a child who took the family ship & came to Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

This was a short story I read. The Earth people were impressed by the alien’s technology, but it turned out that the alien was only a child and had no way to communicate anything of importance about his home planet, nor could he get home.

Comment: Can you remember roughly when you would have read this? If so you can [edit] that and anything else you can remember into your post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The old Theodore Sturgeon story [Mewhu's Jet](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41158) has this plot.

It ends

> "Much good will it do us - and him, poor kid. With a kid's faith in
> any intelligent adult, he's probably been sure we'd get him home
> somehow. Well, we haven't got what it takes, and won't have for a
> long, long time. We don't even know enough to start duplicating that
> jet of his - and that was just a little kid's toy on his world."